# Moving an Object In Gazebo using ROS2 Terminal Commands

Tags: terminal, ros2, gazebo-simu

I have a project in which I have to move a cube in a Gazebo simulation. I need to do so using the terminal.

I recently had Ubuntu 21.10 with Gazebo 11 and ROS1 Noetic installed and had this working perfectly. I essentially just followed this tutorial: [How to Move a Gazebo Model from Terminal](https://varhowto.com/how-to-move-a-gazebo-model-from-command-line-ros/)

But I had to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 and I now have Gazebo 11.10.2 and ROS2 Humble.

I was able to get the current position of the cube thanks to this post:

[/gazebo/get_model_state in ROS2 not present](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28323/gazeboget_model_state-in-ros2-not-present/)

So I modified my world file and used the command: `ros2 service call /get_entity_state gazebo_msgs/GetEntityState '{name: cube1, reference_frame: world}'` and I was able to get the location of the cube.

I figured the reverse would be something like: `ros2 service call /set_entity_state gazebo_msgs/SetEntityState '{name: cube1, Pose:position{x:20, y:0, z:0}, reference_frame: world}'` but I get an error saying `Failed to populate field: 'SetEntityState_Request' object has no attribute 'name'`. However, running `ros2 interface show gazebo_msgs/srv/SetEntityState` we can see that 'name' absolutely is an attribute:

```
gazebo_msgs/EntityState state   # Entity state to set to.
    string name                 #
                                # An entity can be a model, link, collision, light, etc.
                                # Be sure to use gazebo scoped naming notation (e.g. [model_name::link_name])
    geometry_msgs/Pose pose     #
        Point position
            float64 x
            float64 y
            float64 z
        Quaternion orientation
            float64 x 0
            float64 y 0
            float64 z 0
            float64 w 1
    geometry_msgs/Twist twist   #
        Vector3  linear
            float64 x
            float64 y
            float64 z
        Vector3  angular
            float64 x
            float64 y
            float64 z
    string reference_frame      #
                                # Leaving empty or "world" defaults to inertial world frame.
                                # Be sure to fill all fields, values of zero have meaning.
---
bool success                    # Return true if setting state was successful.
```

So I am unsure of the syntax and the documentation that I could find does not really help:

[ROS 2 Documentation: Humble](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Services/Understanding-ROS2-Services.html#ros2-service-call)

[ROS 2 Migration: gazebo_ros_api_plugin](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-gazebo_ros_api_plugin)

[ROS 2 Migration: Entity states](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Entity-states)

Should I use `ros2 topic pub` as in this tutorial: [How to Simulate a Robot Using Gazebo and ROS 2](https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-simulate-a-robot-using-gazebo-and-ros-2/)? If so, how? What is the syntax? I've also tried modifying the the output of GetEntityState and pasting into the argument of SetEntityState but get errors relating to the input being a string and not a dictionary, and other various syntax errors.

TL;DR: How do I move an object in Gazebo using ROS2 commands from the terminal, such as in this tutorial: [How to Move a Gazebo Model from Terminal](https://varhowto.com/how-to-move-a-gazebo-model-from-command-line-ros/)?

Thank you.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. Here is the syntax:
`ros2 service call /gazebo/set_entity_state gazebo_msgs/SetEntityState "state: {name: cube1, pose: {position:{x: 10.5, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}, reference_frame: world}"`